# Video Streaming Python 3 adaptation failling - need help to adapt few lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, video, socket.io, video-streaming

I've almost been successful in adapting a Python 2 code for video and html streaming to Python 3 (actually, the streaming works for html files). Unfortunately, I was unsuccessful to adapt the central part marked inside the following code. I'll greatly appreciate some help

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from socketserver import ThreadingMixIn
import time


class CamHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):


    def do_GET(self):
        #self.path handles the path of the request typed by the client in his browser or his other client program. 
        #For example, the client may have typed http://127.0.0.1:8080/cam.mjpg or http://127.0.0.1:8080/file.html. 
        #Here, we check only the suffix of the path to serve the client.
        if self.path.endswith('.mjpg'):
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=--jpgboundary')
            self.end_headers()

            while True:   
                try:
                    rc, img = capture.read()
                    if not rc:
                        continue
                    imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                    jpg = Image.fromarray(imgRGB)
               #-----------------------------------------------------                             
              #This fragment of code does not work for Python 3:      

                    #tmpFile = StringIO() #Python 2, don't work with Python3
                    #jpg.save(tmpFile, 'JPEG') #Python 2, replaced by
                    self.wfile.write(bytes('--jpgboundary', 'utf8'))
                    self.send_header('Content-type', 'image/jpeg')
                    #self.send_header('Content-length', str(tmpFile.len)) #Python 2, replaced by
                    self.send_header('Content-length', str(jpg.size[0]*jpg.size[1])) #this seems to be bad 

                    self.end_headers()

                    jpg.save(self.wfile, 'JPEG') #makes Python3 crashes
                    time.sleep(0.04)                       
               #end of not working fragment     
               #-----------------------------------------------------         

                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    break
            return

        if self.path.endswith('.html'): # The streaming here works for Python 3:    
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(bytes('<html><head>Hello world</head><body>', 'utf8')) 
            return            


class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""



def main():

    global capture

    capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320) 
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)
    capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_SATURATION, 0.2)

    try:
        server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), CamHandler)
        print('server started', flush = True)
        server.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        capture.release()
        server.socket.close()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Not sure the cause of the crash, but a work around is to replace the problem line with `self.wfile.write( tmpFile.getvalue() )` See [source](https://gist.github.com/n3wtron/4624820?__hstc=50670390.bf88e972fdd7a7debc8575bac5a80cf7.1468281600076.1468281600077.1468281600078.1&__hssc=50670390.1.1468281600079&__hsfp=3105786926#gistcomment-1959363)